# Newb regex help: string with ampersand, using R

Tags: r, regex

I known this should be simple but I cannot return a subset of characters from a string using `regex in R`.

> Foo <- 'propertyid=R206411&state_id='
>
> Reg <- 'propertyid=(.*)&state_id='
>
> Test <- grep(pattern=Reg, x=Foo, value=TRUE)

This captures the entire string for me and I want to capture just the `R206411`. The string I want to capture might vary in length and content, so the key is to have the capture begin after the `'=' in propertyid=`, and then end the capture once it sees the `'&' in '&state_id'`.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use positive lookbehind and lookahead assertions like this:

```
Foo <- 'propertyid=R206411&state_id='
Reg <- gregexpr('(?<=propertyid=).*(?=&state_id=)', Foo, perl=TRUE)
regmatches(Foo, Reg)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `grep` doesn't play well with captured groups which is what you are trying to do. What you probably want is `gsub`

```
Foo <- 'propertyid=R206411&state_id='
Reg <- 'propertyid=(.*)&state_id='
gsub(Reg, "\\1", Foo)
# [1] "R206411"
```

Here we take your pattern, and we replace the match with "\1" (and since R requires us to escape backslashes we double the slash) which stands for the first capture group (which is what the parenthesis indicate). So since you match the whole string, it will replace the whole string with just the matching portion.

Answer (score 0):

The [strapplyc](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ahttp://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/gsubfn/docs/strapply) function in the [gsubfn](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) package can do exactly that.  Using `Foo` and `Reg` from the question:

```
> library(gsubfn)
>
> strapplyc(Foo, Reg, simplify = TRUE)
[1] "R206411"
```